# TyperError: Cannot read property "length" of undefined --- but it is defined?

Tags: arrays, typeerror

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at buildTable (test.js:14)
    at test.js:2

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here. I am getting this error, it seems like its saying my array is undefined, but it is defined?

edit: its referring to the code in the loop.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableBody");
buildTable();

var toDoArray = [];


function buildTable(){

var retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("task");
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);
var addTheTaskName = parsedObject.taskName;
var addTheTaskDate = parsedObject.taskDate;

for(i=0; i < toDoArray.length; i++){
  addTaskToTable(parsedObject[i]);
}



}

function addTaskToTable(obj){
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellDate = row.insertCell(1);
  var cellId = row.insertCell(2);
  var cellCheck = row.insertCell(3);
  cellName.innerHTML= obj.name;
  cellDate.innerHTML= obj.date;
  var checkStuff = "<input type='checkbox'>";
  cellCheck.innerHTML = checkStuff;

}

function submitForm(name,date) {
    var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
    var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
    var taskSomething = getTaskObj(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
      toDoArray.push(taskSomething);
      addTaskToTable(taskSomething);
      var storedArray = JSON.stringify(toDoArray);
      localStorage.setItem("task",storedArray);
};

function getTaskObj(taskName,taskData){
var taskObject = {
        name: taskName,
        date: taskData,
      };
 return taskObject;
}
```

Comment: you are using arry in function and calling function before defining array. See my ans hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep this before you call builtTable function

var toDoArray = [];

like

```
var toDoArray = [];
buildTable();
```

you are calling funtion and using array before defining..

Comment: ahh thank you ... why is it always the simplest things that get me stuck >.>

Comment: welcome :) no worries it happens ... consider accepting ans if it works for you :)